# Arabic letters being cut on iPhoneX

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I've bought an iPhone X about 3 months ago, 1 month later I started facing a problem where some Arabic letters and words are being cut and not shown in the messages in Messenger, Facebook, Line and even the Messages app. While the same messages are shown normally if I come back later.

It happens from time to time, but recently it became so much worse. The English text is shown without any problem

Currently I'm running iOS 11.2.6

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but have you tried to put the global language of the iPhone in Arabic?
Applications can change behavior.

Comment: Thanx .. tried it, but didn't fix the problem

Comment: I noticed that it's on App that are from App store, but what about Messages ? Does it has the same behaviour ?

Comment: yes.. Messages also has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you may need to try a backup and restore of your iPhone software.

But check with another iPhone user 1st and see if they experience any cut off Arabic text on their machine (They may need to download the Arabic language).